# сброс всех настроек Excel 2010

Tags: excel

Подскажите пожалуйста как сбросить все настройки Excel 2010 по умолчанию чтоб были в итоге, как будто только что установил?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не связан с программированием и администрированием.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не связан с программированием и администрированием.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого случая простой чудо-кнопки еще не придумали )

Можно переустановить *Microsoft Office*, но обычно это мало помогает, т.к. в

системе остаются хвосты.

**Вариант1**. Самый простой, но наименее действенный (а вдруг?). Заменить шаблон.

Шаблон *Excel-2003* искать по пути:

*C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Microsoft\Excel\Excel11.xlb*

*Excel-2010* хранит свой шаблон в другом месте:

*C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\Excel14.xlb*

**Вариант2**. Требует навыков и минимальных знаний системы. Удалить *Microsoft Office*  через удаление программ.

Заглянуть в *C:\Program Files*. Там может остаться папка *Microsoft Office*. Удалить ее.

Пройтись по папкам пользователей (*C:\Users*), в скрытых поискать папки, связанные с

Офисом (*Excel, Word*, те же *Microsoft Office*), удалить их.

*Выполнить-regedit* - почистить  в реестре регистрационные записи *Office*.

Установить офис, новенький и чистенький.

**Вариант3**. Поискать программы для сброса прараметров офисных приложений.

**Вариант4**. Самый радикальный - преустановить систему - поможет гарантированно, но вряд-ли рассматривается.